# Свой List из array

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, указатели, список

Пытаюсь создать свой list из array

есть структура

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next; 
};
```

собственно функция

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>* arrayToList(const T tab[], size_t size){

Node<T> *node = new Node<T>;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
node->data = tab[i];
node->next = new Node<T>;
}
}
```

в main

```
    int tabi[] = {2,1,4,3,6,5,7,8};
size_t sizei = sizeof(tabi)/sizeof(tabi[0]);
Node<int> *listAi = arrayToList(tabi,sizei);
```

так вот проблема в том что не могу править созданный экземпляр Node тут `node->next = new Node<T>;` я создаю экземпляр , а как в него значение из массива занести ?

Comment: Я не понял, что значит "я не могу править созданный экземпляр"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не понятно, в чем состоит ваша проблема

Поэтому я предложу код, который позволяет заполнить список элементами массива. Надеюсь, что если это не то, что вам нужно, то вы об этом сообщите  мне в своем комментарии к ответу.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node 
{
    T data;
    Node *next; 
};

template <typename T>
Node<T> * arrayToList( const T a[], size_t n )
{
    Node<T> *head = nullptr;
    Node<T> **current = &head;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++, current = &( *current )->next )
    {
        *current = new Node<T> { a[i], nullptr };         
    }

    return head;
}

template <typename T>
void displayList( Node<T> *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next ) std::cout << head->data << ' ';
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7, 8 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Node<int> *list = arrayToList( a, N );

    displayList( list );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
2 1 4 3 6 5 7 8 
2 1 4 3 6 5 7 8
```

Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает список инициализации для оператора `new`, то предложение

```
*current = new Node<T> { a[i], nullptr };
```

вы можете заменить на следующие предложения

```
*current = new Node<T>;         
( *current )->data = a[i];
( *current )->next = nullptr;
```

Либо вы можете написать для класса `Node` конструктор, чтобы можно было бы опять записать все в одну строчку, как, например

```
*current = new Node<T>( a[i], nullptr );
```